# Request not supported: RemoveMember/AddMember/SetStateDynamicEntity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I was analyzing the trace logs from production server for my MS CRM 2011 deployment with UR18 and observed that there are multiple entries for the below exceptions -

```
Message: Request not supported: RemoveMember, ErrorCode: -2147220715

Message: Request not supported: AddMember, ErrorCode: -2147220715

Message: Request not supported: SetStateDynamicEntity, ErrorCode: -2147220715
```

The trace log for AddMember is something like below.

I did not get any clue from this log. I even searched for the supported messages for MS CRM 2011 which shows that these messages are supported.

Did anybody face such issue or have any clue around this? All inputs are appreciated. :)

```
at ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)  ilOffset = 0x86
at QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()  ilOffset = 0x23
at ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()  ilOffset = 0x81
at _ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()  ilOffset = 0x51
Crm Exception: Message: Request not supported: AddMember, ErrorCode: -2147220715
```